# I get an error with the jar files when running the Android app

Tags: java, android, jar

I was using Eclipse. Now I'm experimenting with the same application in Android Studio. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    File1: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpclient-4.3.6.jar
    File2: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpcore-4.3.3.jar
    File3: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpmime-4.3.6.jar
```

Build.Gradle: The module's contents are as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mobilokul"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
```

When the value `packagingOptions` is deleted, the error is as follows.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpclient-4.3.6.jar
    File2: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpcore-4.3.3.jar
    File3: C:\Android\as_workspace\MobilOkul\app\libs\httpmime-4.3.6.jar
```

Comment: check you have duplicate jar present in project.

Comment: exclude `META-INF/DEPENDENCIES` same as you excluded `'META-INF/NOTICE' `, etc.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle with

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```